# What should we do about new series tag wikis?

Tags: discussion, tag-wiki

When a user wants to ask about an specific anime they are usually creating new tags adding no info to them. For example:

[What exactly is “Paradise”?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/3062/what-exactly-is-paradise) [wolfs-rain](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wolfs-rain)

[Did all the townsfolk know that Yuki is a wolf?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/3068/did-all-the-townsfolk-know-that-yuki-is-a-wolf) [wolfs-children](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wolfs-children)

[What part of Tiger & Bunny do purple, white, and green plastic bins refer to?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/what-part-of-tiger-bunny-do-purple-white-and-green-plastic-bins-refer-to) [tiger-and-bunny](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tiger-and-bunny)

**What should we do with these tags? Should we start to add info to every tag added?**

**Yes**

List of Tags without Description:

- [ubel-blatt](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ubel-blatt)
- [umineko-no-naku-koro-ni](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/umineko-no-naku-koro-ni)
- [wolfs-rain](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wolfs-rain)
- [wolf-children](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wolf-children)
- [yu-gi-oh](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/yu-gi-oh)
- [tiger-and-bunny](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tiger-and-bunny)
- [toki-wo-kakeru-shoujo](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/toki-wo-kakeru-shoujo)
- [wasurenagumo](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/wasurenagumo)
- [sakamoto-desu-ga](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sakamoto-desu-ga)
- [saki](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/saki)
- [psycho-pass](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/psycho-pass)
- [mushrambo](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mushrambo)
- [mangirl](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mangirl)
- [mnemosyne](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mnemosyne)
- [maoyuu-maou-yuusha](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maoyuu-maou-yuusha)
- [oban-star-racers](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oban-star-racers)
- [parody](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parody)
- [banana-no-nana](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/banana-no-nana)
- [boku-no-imouto-osaka-okan](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/boku-no-imouto-osaka-okan)
- [conventions](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conventions)
- [kimi-ni-todoke](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kimi-ni-todoke)
- [kobato](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kobato)
- [koi-choco](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/koi-choco)
- [last-wish-to-shinigami](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/last-wish-to-shinigami)
- [le-fruit-de-la-grisaia](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/le-fruit-de-la-grisaia)
- [little-busters](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/little-busters)
- [live-action](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/live-action)
- [magi](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magi)
- [maken-ki](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/maken-ki)
- [howls-moving-castle](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/howls-moving-castle)
- [hataraku-maou-sama](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hataraku-maou-sama)

As this Tags get description or new tags are added i will update the list.

Comment: Do you want people to start going through and deleting in the post after they edit the tag wikis?

Comment: Well I was going to add the wiki info this weekend but if someone else is willing to help great...

Comment: Oh, I've been starting to add to wikis on the list. I can just delete the ones that I do as I go.

Comment: Of course do it ;).

Answer (score 5):

**Yes.**

IMO, if the tag is proper (i.e. not an odd meta-tag or a series that doesn't exist/is unrelated), then it should have a tag wiki entry. This is the case *especially* for new or less popular tags, when we want them to be visible and entice people to use them.

I really don't see any reason to *not* add the tag wikis. If they aren't helpful or need to be removed, we will either decline the edit or have someone remove the entry.

Comment: Agreed. It's worth noting that the most important cases to write tag wikis are if the series is likely to be asked about again and/or the tag is somehow ambiguous. [tag:girls-und-panzer] is probably not so important to get a wiki, since it's obvious what it refers to and it's not a hugely popular series. On the other hand, if you use abbreviations or the series is known by multiple names, a tag wiki is important.

Comment: Also, [this meta question](http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/questions/385/how-do-i-write-a-good-tag-wiki) addresses the question of how to write a good tag wiki. Note that it isn't acceptable to just copy from some other source. That constitutes plagarism and your edit will be rejected if we notice this.

Comment: Yes, that's kinda how tags work. They are born out of need, and upgraded when possible (with wikis and excerpts).